# How to store images and some text in android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose, android-database

I'm about to make an android app something like "fun places to visit in my city" where u can see photos and description of the place.

I thought something like store all images in drawable folder, and create list of data class.
But the app will be very heavy?

I dont know which is the best way to store data and images locally. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to keep app light maybe the better approach would be to store them somewhere on cloud and load them using library like [picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/).

Storing them directly in the app truly can increase apk size a lot because you also should store different sizes of every images if you are following guidelines.

Comment: Yeah I could store them somewhere online, but is there any free image hosting?
I've read that somebody store images on dropbox but isnt it illegal or sth to use it as image hosting to my app which I probably publish?

Comment: Safest bet for you then would be to build your own platform and host them yourself. You can set up server locally for testing and if you like how the app is going you can rent server online for like $5 a month. For hosting all you need is engine and to serve images as static resources. Here is a guide for Nginx to get you started https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/.
P.S. you could also use Apache server but nginx my preference

Comment: Thank you, I will think about it.

Comment: You are very welcome, just don't give up if it gets hard